# how to get character of contenteditable in the attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am japanese.
I'm sorry, but I'm not good at English!

I am creating web editer(like wordpress) using html5 contenteditable attribute.

Press enter in the elements that have adapted the contenteditable , you can create a div tag.
Character of the div tag is I want to determine whether not the case whether it is a empty .

I wrote this codes.

```
<div class="c-contenteditable" contenteditable="true" id="js-editable"></div>


//In this case, console.log is all charactor in this element. I want to single line words, not all.
$('#js-editable').on('keyup', function(e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  var text = $this.text();
  if ($this.text() == '') {
    console.log('no words');
  }else{
    console.log(text);
  }
});

//In this case, keyup t`enter code here`rigger is not run.
$('#js-editable div').on('keyup', function(e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  var text = $this.text();
  if ($this.text() == '') {
    console.log('no words');
  }else{
    console.log(text);
  }
});

//In this case, keyup trigger is not run.
$('#js-editable').find('div').on('keyup', function(e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  var text = $this.text();
  if ($this.text() == '') {
    console.log('no words');
  }else{
    console.log(text);
  }
});
```

The How might be able to get a string in div tags generated when you press the enter in contenteditable attribute?

Comment: use wrap function of jquery to wrap the content.

Comment: thank you! sorry, I dont understand how to use wrap function of jquery.